# How to create animations with tailwind?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

How to create animations with tailwind?

I am interested in animating text when page loads - text animated
https://static.collectui.com/shots/4218498/zet-pageload-large

I am trying to use the tailwind-elements library, but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-around w-full">
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center flex-col mt-0 mb-auto">
        <h3 className="p-10 font-extrabold text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r from-slate-950 to-stone-400 text-7xl">
          text here <== This text I need animate
        </h3>
        <span className="p-5 font-normal text-3xl text-neutral-600">
          text here
        </span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Image <== And this image I need animate
          className="rounded-3xl shadow-2xl"
          src="/main_jpg.jpg"
          width={500}
          height={500}
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: There is no animation code in your question, that's why it's not animating. Did you read the documentation? https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/content-styles/animations/

Comment: Oops, I deleted animations and copied code here. But before code with tailwind-elements was and not works)